# Hi, I'm a beginner

Tags: encryption

I'm 15.
I hope you answer my question.
I don't have any background on encryption.
Thank you for introducing me with books that will take me step by step.
I know pythons, not very well, but I know things.

Comment: FIrst of all, welcome to Cryptography.SE. This is off-topic here. You may start reading the David Khan's book for the history and John F. Dooley
's book A Brief History of
Cryptology and
Cryptographic
Algorithms. In the meantime, start to make strong your math and computer skills. Knowing python is a start about coding, real crypto uses higher languages like C/C++ etc.

Comment: @kelalaka Isn't C/C++ a much lower language than Python by computer science definition :-) Did you mean harder rather than higher?

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you.

Comment: Modern Cryptography: Applied Mathematics for Encryption and Information Security
by Chuck Easttom

Comment: @PaulUszak yes, I did not use the term in the common usage like the low-level languages. I've used in the sense that thye have higher control of the output, anyway, I should have been used the common usage. Also, note that one should learn probability very well since modern cryptography is based on probability, too.